# How to view npc's movement speed in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

What is the console command that displays the movement speed of npcs?

I want to check which Automatron is the fastest.

Comment: Hmm... that's a good question. I'm not sure I've ever seen anything related to **base** movement speed in the console, just `speedmult`. I know your character's speed is altered by the `speedmult` factor, NPCs might be the same way... does clicking the NPC and using the command `player.getav speedmult` provide any info on it?

Comment: Can't help you with that, but based on the text descriptions and my in-game experience, the Mr. Handy thruster is the fastest set of legs.

Comment: That may be true but what about sentry legs with the speed upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

To get the speed of a robot as it is moving, open the console, click on the robot, and type:

```
getgraphvariablefloat speed
```

If it doesn't work, make sure you have a clear path to the robot. Even if you do have a clear path, often you will find that you have not actually clicked on the robot but rather a nearly invisible field of mist placed in the cell, or whatever. You may have to walk right up to one to click on it depending on the area.

Most biological NPCs have fspeedwalk and fspeedrun that you could use to get the supposed speeds of their walk and run for their current movement type (the type will differ if they have weapons sighted/equipped/etc.) but that probably wouldn't help anyway as the robots most likely all have the same default movement speeds which are then adjusted by speedmult. To get the speedmult, select a robot with the console open and type:

`getav speedmult`

This may give you the difference without having to lead them along typing the first line. 1 is 100% of normal speed, 1.05 is a 5% increase, etc.

Note that getgraphvariablefloat speed will give you net speed going forward or backward, etc., and may change depending on a decrease or increase in acceleration, so check it a few times while a robot is moving, ideally when the robot is moving fast.